# phonegap: trying to store json in database:

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, web-sql

I am trying to store an entry with the following json String in a database. However, it seems like the format of the json string is not agreeing with the db even though I have read articles saying this should be easy:

I have tried:

```
function Activity() {
    this.clicks = 100;
    this.activityTypeCode = 3;
}

    var anActivity=new Activity(); 
    var jsonString=JSON.stringify(anActivity);
    database.transaction(function(tx) {
         tx.executeSQL('INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID, DATA) VALUES (100,'+jsonString+')');  
    }, errorCB, successCB)

;
```

and I get an error that says error unrecognized token "{". 
when I do console.log(jsonString) I get:

```
{"clicks":100, "activityTypeCode":3}
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a db? It might be easier to store the data in something less complex, especially if you don't have much data.

Comment: For starters, you need to provide two values in your sql query, an id and your data.

Comment: Am storing it this way using a much more complex object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is to make sure that your json string is correct. You can validate your json string here.

Second debug is you are missing a ';' in your insert statement in executeSQL. The value array is missing as well.

Third debug would be your executeSQL statement. Try this:

```
    database.transaction(function(tx) 
    {
      tx.executeSQL('INSERT INTO MYTABLE(ID, DATA) VALUES (?,?);', [100, jsonString],                 
        errorCB, successCB);
     }
```

Have you declared ID as AUTOINCREMENT? You cant assign values to an AUTOINCREMENT column.

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized query or quoted string

```
database.transaction(function(tx) {
     tx.executeSQL('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MYTABLE (ID, DATA) VALUES (100,?)');  
}, [jsonString], errorCB, successCB)
```